# setBackgroundResource for button not working

Tags: android, xml, setbackground

I am new to android app development. I am trying to build 2048 game. I used images for tiles and loaded them for every swipe. At first i got `memoryOutOfBounds` Exception. Later i changed the largeHeap to true and it worked but is bit slow. So, i replaced the images with xml background and used buttons. But now my app is not working. `onSwipe` functions are not getting invoked. After swiping for many number of times then i am able to make a move that too woth incorrect background colours. Please help me figure this out.

```
 Button b[][] =new Button[4][4];
GestureDetector gestureDetector;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int idd[][] = {{R.id.block00, R.id.block01, R.id.block02, R.id.block03},
            {R.id.block10, R.id.block11, R.id.block12, R.id.block13},
            {R.id.block20, R.id.block21, R.id.block22, R.id.block23},
            {R.id.block30, R.id.block31, R.id.block32, R.id.block33}};
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
           b[i][j] = (Button)findViewById(idd[i][j]);
    start();
    draw();
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);
}
```

code for draw function

```
 public void draw()
{
        int i,j;
        int img[] = {R.drawable.t0, R.drawable.t2, R.drawable.t4, R.drawable.t8, R.drawable.t16, R.drawable.t32, R.drawable.t64, R.drawable.t128, R.drawable.t256, R.drawable.t512, R.drawable.t1024, R.drawable.t2048, R.drawable.t4096, R.drawable.t8192, R.drawable.t16384, R.drawable.t32768, R.drawable.t65536, R.drawable.t131072};

        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                if(grid[i][j]!=0)
                    b[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(grid[i][j]));
                b[i][j].setBackgroundResource(img[log2(grid[i][j])]);
            }
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.best);
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(score));
    tv1.setText(Integer.toString(best));

}
```

When i changed the xml object from button to ImageView and the code inside draw from setBackgroundResource to setImageResource, it is working fine.

one of the drawable xml files(t1024.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<padding
    android:left="4dp"
    android:top="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:bottom="4dp"/>
<corners android:radius="6dp"/>
<solid android:color="#1a1d23"/>
```

All drawable resources contain the same code, i just changed the `android:color` attribute.

Comment: i hope u tried setImageResource(R.drawable.t1024);

Comment: try Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ready)

Comment: setImageResource() is working for ImageViews but i am having problem 
 with buttons @vikaskumar

Comment: did you tried drawable using ContextCompat

Comment: yes i tried it but not working. There is no problem with setImageResource() or ContextCompat. When i am using buttons it is not working. When i changed the xml object to ImageView it is working. Is there any problem using swipe when i have buttons on my layoout.@vikaskumar